# Excluir carpeta en una búsqueda de archivos Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo

Tengo un código en el que me localiza los archivos de una carpeta, por nombre y los mueve a otra ruta establecida.

```
import os, shutil
files = os.listdir('C:/Users/Python/Test')

one = "one"
two = "two"
oney = "pepe"
twoy="jose"

def findfile(x,y):
    for file in files:
        if x in file.lower():
            while x in file.lower():
              src = ('C:/Users/Python/Test/'+''.join(file))
              dest = ('C:/Users/Python/Test/'+y)
              if not os.path.exists(dest):
                os.makedirs(dest)
              shutil.move(src,dest)
              break

findfile(one,oney)
findfile(two,twoy)
```

El caso, este programita mueve todos los archivos de la carpeta **Test** a otra ruta dependiendo del nombre, pongamos **one** como ejemplo:

Si hay un `.png` llamado "one", lo moverá a la carpeta "pepe". El problema viene en que en mi código no se hace distinción entre tipos de archivos y lo que me gustaría es que excluyera de la búsqueda las carpetas.

Si hay una carpeta llamada "one", que no la mueva a la carpeta "pepe", que
solo lo mueva si es una carpeta!! Los demás archivos si debe moverlos.

Los archivos de la carpeta **contienen** la string `one`, no se llaman exactamente así.

No sé si me he explicado muy bien, si algo no queda claro dejadme un comentario e intentaré explicarlo mejor!

Gracias de antemano!!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias soluciones a tu problema, yo creo que lo más sencillo es cambiar la búsqueda y poner un `.`, por ejemplo:

Si tienes la carpeta `one` y un archivo `one.png`, en vez de buscar `one`, busca `one.`. Si tiene una extensión es que no es una carpeta.

si bien como comenta @abufalia si tienes carpetas con puntos en los nombres esto no funcionará.

**Opción 2**

Siempre puedes usar de la librería de Python `os` la función `isfile()` o `isdir()`, sería así:

```
import os
os.path.isfile("path/hacia/one.png") #comprobamos si es un fichero
os.path.isdir("path/hacia/one") #comprobamos si es un directorio
```

Estas dos funciones como ves en el ejemplo se les pasa una dirección y  devuelven `True` o `False`.

En el caso de `isdir()` devolverá `True` si se encuentra un directorio y `False` si se encuentra un archivo y con `isfile` lo contrario.

[Aquí](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) puedes encontrar la documentación de ambas funciones

Comment: La opción de añadirle un punto sería buena, el problema es que los archivos tal vez no se llamen `one`, puede darse el caso de que haya uno llamado `ones.png`, `onemadrid.jpg`. Son ejemplos, pero creo que se entiende. Gracias!

Comment: Lo del punto no es suficientemente genérico. Los nombres de carpeta también pueden contener un punto, aunque no sea lo usual. La correcta es la opción 2.

Comment: He implementado la opción 2 pero no funciona. `File "d:\Python\backup.py", line 21, in <module>
    findfile(one,oney)
  File "d:\Python\backup.py", line 11, in findfile
    for file in files:
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`

Comment: No tengáis en cuenta la ruta, estoy trabajando en un USB y es normal que canvie.

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta con como has realizado dicha implementación por favor, el error te dice que estás intentando iterar por un booleano, es decir hacer algo como `for i in True` lo cual no es posible. Es decir en tu variable `files` tienes un booleano, supongo que porque has usado `isdir` o `isfile` pero no correctamente.

Comment: He modificado el `files = os.listdir` por `files = os.path.isfile`

Comment: No, no, de hecho lo he quedado así porque considero que es relativamente sencillo de implementar, hay que pensar en lo que se hace e ir con paciencia. `listdir()` te dice todos los archivos que contiene una determinada carpeta, luego eso no lo puedes quitar porque es lo que usas para ir iterando por lo que hay en la carpeta. `isdir()` o `isfile()` te dice si dicho archivo por el que iteras es un directorio o un archivo. Te amplio la respuesta, porque si es cierto que no había explicado exactamente que hacen  ¡Tomate tu tiempo para implementar dichas funciones!

Comment: no acabo de comprender muy bien como realizar la implementación de `isfile()` que indicas. Entiendo que solo sirve para comprobar si existe el archivo o el directorio, cosa que no se que tan útil es para este caso

Comment: No, sirve para que te indique si es un archivo o no es un archivo `isfile()`, como indico en la respuesta. Lo que tienes que hacer antes de llegar al fichero que quieres mover, es crear `if` que si te devuelve True lo mueva. Ejemplo `if os.isfile(src): shutil.move(src,dest)`. Que viene a decir, si os.isfile(src) es verdadero (esta función devuelve verdadero si es un archivo) entonces muevelo porque es un archivo. No malinterpretes el texto escrito por favor, estoy siendo amable y solo quiero que le des vueltas a lo que estás haciendo y que lo entiendas, para que lo puedas implementar tu mismo

Comment: Para mí sería más sencillo darte tu código que copies y pegues y ya está. Pero creo que en el fondo no te sería de mucha utilidad a ti, a medio/largo plazo.

Comment: En absoluto! Gracias por tu ayuda, prefiero darle vueltas y averiguarlo a obtenerlo todo hecho por otro usuario. Ya lo he solucionado usando la función `os.walk(ruta)`